# redirect a post request in IE using 307

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess, http, redirect, post

i have a serious issue with our beloved Internet Explorer.

i have the following redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^add/(.*)/$ /_ucp/moduls/$1/add/add.php [L,R=307]
```

R=308 causes a complete server crash, don't know why 
(this is the last row in the htacces file)

the definition for 307 is

> In contrast to how 302 was historically implemented, the request
>   method is not allowed to be changed when reissuing the original
>   request. For instance, a POST request repeated using another POST
>   request

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

**THE PROBLEM:**

i think the definition is clear and impossible to missunderstand, thous the damn IE redirects using a GET method! All my post data is lost!

I tracked the redirect using the F12 developer tools.

Does anyone know how to fix / workaround this problem. 
I really don't want to use cryptic urls in my sourcecode :(

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using apache, version 2.2 doesn't support redirecting with the 308 code (307 is supported). However, apache 2.4 **does** support redirecting with the 308 code (at least 2.4.3 does). The 308 code is [in experimental status](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-reschke-http-status-308-07), so you're unlikely to see wide adoption at this point.

According to [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx), IE versions 6-10 handle the 307 redirect silently. I tested this on a copy of IE 9.0.12, and when a POST request was responded with a 307 redirect, the location URL was requested with a POST request like it's supposed to.

Comment: i've read the same blog.
but have a look at this:
http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/2194/iecrap.png

request goes out as POST, 307 is recived, a new GET request goes out.

IE 9

maybe it's only an issue when start a request with JS but still not tolerable!

Comment: @user1972159 Maybe you should check the detailed view, [in my test, it's POST and POST](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jwchM.png) but both are initiated by clicks, and not by what looks like javascript in your case.

Comment: yes, as i said, it looks like it's only a issue when i start the request using jQuery.ajax. Seems the IE doesn't save the method. 
I really appreciate your work :)
Due to the leak of time I'm not able to change this. Its a very complex structure and i never thought this would be a problem. 
although really disappointing :( 
Everytime the IE.....
Well i think this is "solved". Now i use a cryptic url and try to change things in version 2.
Thank you very very much!!!!

unfortunately I can't update apache because its not my own server. (308)

But i'm really thankful. =)